# RadFileExplorer: get selected file names

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadFileExplorer which works ok, uploads and everything work great.

What I want to do is when a user gets to the folder they want they'll select a certain amount of files then when they hit a custom button I want to be able to grab the folder / filename of each file on the server side so I can add those values to a database table.

Can anyone tell me how I can go about this?

Sample code:

```
<telerik:RadFileExplorer  runat="server" ID="FileExplorer1" Width="780px" Height="300px" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15" CssClass="fileBrowser" EnableFilterTextBox="true" DisplayUpFolderItem="False" EnableCreateNewFolder="True" TreePaneWidth="200px" >

<Configuration ViewPaths="~/productImages/"  UploadPaths="~/productImages/" DeletePaths="~/productImages/"  AllowMultipleSelection="True" EnableAsyncUpload="True" SearchPatterns="*.jpg, *.png, *.jpeg, *.gif" MaxUploadFileSize="2097152" ></Configuration>

</telerik:RadFileExplorer>
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 2):

You need to get all selected files and want ro retrieve the fhe folder and filename for instance, am I right?
Like mentioned in [telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer-client-side.html) there is a function get_selectedItems()
that returns an array of the selected items on the Grid items. The items are of type Telerik.Web.UI.FileExplorerItem().